# How to add temporal Julia environment in in Jupyter

Tags: julia, jupyter

I know how to add Julia environment in Jupyter chunk

```
Pkg.activate("../EEG_plots/env")
```

I know how to create temporal env in Julia REPL

```
 pkg> activate --temp
```

But what if I want just temporal one? How could I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the same way - IJulia supports the Pkg REPL mode:

```
] activate --temp
```

(just to be clear you just put the square bracket at the start of the cell, the prompt doesn't change if course in the notebook but IJulia will interpret the cell as Pkg REPL input)

Alternatively there's the non REPL mode based API which is `Pkg.activate(temp=true)`